# Unable to debug in PyCharm. Says "No project interpreter", but it is configured

Tags: python, pycharm

I am unable to use the debugger in PyCharm. Looking around for an answer, the first thing I came across was to use the project interpreter.

If I go to the top left, "Edit Configurations" and de-select "Use Project Interpreter", then the code runs just fine, but the option to debug is grayed-out.

If I select "Use project interpreter", then go to settings and set the project interpreter to be the same one, I can't run the code at all, let alone debug it. Upon selecting the option, the message "!Error: No project interpreter configured" pops up immediately... but it *is* configured!

Settings:[image]

Run/Debug Configurations:[image]

Followed these instructions to set up my project from an existing Conda environment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

I have made sure I clicked "apply" and also restarted PyCharm after that. This doesn't seem complicated, and at this point I have no idea what I can possibly be missing.

Comment: Based on the second screenshot, it seems like the issue is that you're trying to use a `Bash` environment

Comment: That was it, thank you

Comment: Maybe so this question can be useful to others in the future, you could self-answer this question with how you accidentally got into that state as well as how you fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The error was caused because I was using the Bash template instead of the Python template to set up my run configuration. This occurred because I had previously used PyCharm to run a bash script, and the option to create a Python template was collapsed by default, leading me to not realize my mistake.